# How do you setup a Grid in Vaadin 8 to sort by a custom comparator?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

So for example my grid is composed of `People` so that I have:

```
public class People
{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

My grid is such that I have:

`grid.addColumn(People::getName).setId("Name");`

Now I know I can do:

```
grid.sort("Name", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
```

The problem is what if I have two people with the same name, say John. In this case I want to first sort by `name` and then by `id`. The id is not a column in the grid, it's just a property of the `People` class.

Although this example is oversimplified I do include additional information so it's important that I'm able to sort by the actual person and not just the name. In my case the grid is a report and the person's name is just one of many fields.

Comment: I think you would have to deal with that in your data source.  E.g. always add a last, implicit sort by id.

Comment: You could also include ID as column? What's the actual data source?

Comment: I do setup an ID, in this case it's "Name". The datasource is a List<People>, in that it's not linked to anything directly and managed from legacy systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it, assuming you have a list of Cars with People being one of the columns, is:

```
Grid<Car> grid = new Grid<Car>();
grid.addColumn(Car::getPerson).setComparator((car1, car2) -> 
{
    // ignoring any null checks for getPerson() as they can be null.
    return car1.getPerson().compareTo(car2.getPerson());               
});
```